# Add tabs to one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am trying to add tabs to just one fragment in my app (the app has several fragments).  I am going round in circles trying to get this to work. I have found some advice from a stackoverflow answer that was posted to someones question but this crashes my app.

Fragment code
   public class salesPartsHolderFragment extends Fragment {

```
public salesPartsHolderFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View theView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sales_parts_holder, container, false);
    TabHost tabs=(TabHost)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);//here you define which tab you want to setup
    spec.setIndicator("So Close");//here you choose the text showed in the tab
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec=tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Contacts");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    return theView;
}
```

}

XML Code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex.activities.salesPartsHolderFragment">

<TabHost
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/setting" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat

```
02-23 12:52:16.601    4991-4991/com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-23 12:52:16.601    4991-4991/com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa625f288)
02-23 12:52:16.613    4991-4991/com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex.activities.MainActivity.loadSalesPartsFragment(MainActivity.java:244)
            at com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex.activities.SampleFragment.showSalesPartsFragment(SampleFragment.java:292)
            at com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex.activities.SampleFragment.saveDetailsMoveToSalesParts(SampleFragment.java:281)
            at com.alcontrol.atmis.anticimex.activities.SampleFragment$1.onClick(SampleFragment.java:71)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Read about using FragmentTabHost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
TabHost tabs = (TabHost)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

with

```
TabHost tabs = (TabHost)theView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
```

Try this. This will work.

Calling `getActivity.findViewById()` will not work in `onCreateView()`, because the `View` of the `Fragment` has yet to be created by `onCreateView()`.

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: Thanks , I have now added the logcat

Comment: what is at line 244 of `MainActivity` ?? Please also give your `loadSalesPartsFragment()` method code

Comment: I apologise, there was some redundant code in there, I have removed it and it now works :-) .

Comment: with pleasure and done, thanks again, massive help and saved me further hours of hacking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a Tab Activity, in that activity you will add your fragments. I hope below code will help you:

public class TabActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private static TabHost mTabHost;

private TabSpec mTabSpec;

private final String TAG_First = "First";

private final String TAG_Second = "Second";

private final String TAG_Third = "Third";

private int mCurrentTab = 0;
private View mDecorView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost_lesson);
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(mTabChangeListener);
    mTabHost.setup();

    setupTabs();
}

private void setupTabs() {

    /*
     * Setup new tab
     */
    mTabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_First);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(mCurrentTab);
    mTabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        }
    });

    mTabSpec.setIndicator(createTabContent(TAG_First, 14));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabSpec);

    /*
     * Setup New Tab
     */
    mTabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_Second);

    mTabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        }
    });

    mTabSpec.setIndicator(createTabContent(TAG_Second, 14));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabSpec);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);

    /*
     * Setup New Tab
     */
    mTabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_Third);

    mTabSpec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            return findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        }
    });

    mTabSpec.setIndicator(createTabContent(TAG_Third, 14));

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabSpec);

}

/**
 * Method to Customize Tabs
 * 
 * @param String
 *            TabID
 * @param Drawable
 *            drawable
 * @param int TabTextSize
 * @return
 */
public View createTabContent(String mTabLbl, int mTxtSize) {

    View mTabView = LayoutInflater.from(TabActivity.this).inflate(
            R.layout.tabs_background, null);

    TextView mTabText = (TextView) mTabView.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);

    // mTabText.setBackgroundDrawable(mTabDraw);
    mTabText.setText(mTabLbl);

    return mTabView;
}

public static void SetCurrentTab(int CurrentTab) {
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(CurrentTab);
}

TabHost.OnTabChangeListener mTabChangeListener = new OnTabChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

        if (tabId.equals(TAG_First)) {

            mCurrentTab = 0;

            FirstFrag fFragment = new FirstFrag();

            addTabFragments(tabId, fFragment);

        } else if (tabId.equals(TAG_Second)) {

            mCurrentTab = 1;

            SecondFrag sFragment = new SecondFrag();

            addTabFragments(tabId, sFragment);

        } else if (tabId.equals(TAG_Third)) {

            mCurrentTab = 2;

            ThirdFrag tFragment = new ThirdFrag();

            addTabFragments(tabId, tFragment);

        }
    }
};

/**
 * Method to add Fragment When Switching Between Tabs
 * 
 * @param String
 *            Tag
 * @param Fragment
 *            TabFragment
 */
public void addTabFragments(String tag, Fragment mTabFrag) {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, mTabFrag);

    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have a mainAcitivity will all the fragments that have a work flow FragA through to FragF  with FragD being the one that has the tabs.  Are you saying I will have to come out of MainActivity and go into a TabActivity?

Comment: are u trying to add all the tabs in a fragment?

Comment: Yes One fragment will need to display two tabs that will then load content in that fragment

Comment: I have test this code in fragment also, and this work fine. I have main_Activity which call fragment "tabFragment". This tab fragment have 3 tabs...you can use my code from this link   http://simplexandroid.blogspot.in/p/tabs-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

find help with this project [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html). It is recommended by Google instead of TabHost.